# OData PATCH on a custom function result

Tags: odata

I was wondering if it's allowed by OData protocol to do a patch on the result of a custom function, for example let's say an API which has custom function, returns an Entity:

`https://<serviceroot>/api/EntitySet('id')/GetChildEntity(key=entryId)/`

To avoid additional round trips I want the client to be able to further modify the returned entity of GetChildEntity by doing a patch on it so

`PATCH https://<serviceroot>/api/EntitySet('id')/GetChildEntity(key=entryId)/`

Is this allowed by OData protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, per protocol this is support, you can refer to specification (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752310) and the statement is

If the function is composable, additional path segments may be appended to the URL that identifies the composable function (or function import) as appropriate for the type returned by the function (or function import). The last path segment determines the system query options **and HTTP verbs that can be used with this this URL**, e.g. if the last path segment is a multi-valued navigation property, a POST request may be used to create a new entity in the identified collection.